# Querying database but getting null back

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to list the items from my database into my view but I'm getting null back.

I know the connection must be working to a certain extent because in my database the tables didn't exist but once I ran my program it did create the tables. However when I add content into my table my view still returns NULL.

Also, haven't touched the Review table yet, just worried about getting Restaurants working.

## Restaurant.cs

```
namespace OdeToFood.Models
{
    public class Restaurant
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public ICollection<RestaurantReview> Reviews { get; set; }
    }
}
```

## OdeToFood.cs

```
namespace OdeToFood.Models
{
    public class OdeToFoodDb : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RestaurantReview> Reviews { get; set; }
    }
}
```

## Controller

```
OdeToFoodDb _db = new OdeToFoodDb();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = _db.Restaurants.ToList();

    return View();
}
```

## Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<OdeToFood.Models.Restaurant>

@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@{
    if (Model != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div>
                <h4>@item.Name</h4>
                <div>@item.City, @item.Country</div>
                <hr />
            </div>
        }
    }
    else
    {
        <h1>Null</h1>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never actually send the model to the view.  Pass it as an argument:

```
OdeToFoodDb _db = new OdeToFoodDb();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = _db.Restaurants.ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```

Additionally, it's generally a good idea not to create database contexts in a shared scope.  Keep the context as close to where it's used as possible and only expand its scope when you really need to.  Something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (var _db = new OdeToFoodDb())
    {
        var model = _db.Restaurants.ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Database contexts/connections in a shared scope is just asking for problems unless you pay close attention to what you're doing.  As the code gets more complex, it becomes more likely that other methods will try to use it and it may be in an unknown state at that time.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass to model back to the view.

```
OdeToFoodDb _db = new OdeToFoodDb();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = _db.Restaurants.ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```